# What is meaning of word "そらおとり"

Tags: meaning

Sentence:

> そら おとり こんな はしたがねで よければな。

Main problem that this two words written separately, and the verb "おとり" or "とり". I'm sure this is not slang

Context: https://youtu.be/b0s-RxmP73g?t=1388

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> おとり。

It's a mild command form of the verb [取]{と}る. It means (お)取りなさい, "(Please) take it."

「お+連用形。」 form as a mild command sounds pretty old-fashioned. It's informal, and used by 目上の人 (eg mother, teacher) towards 目下の人. Some phrases are still in use in our daily conversation. eg:

> 「お[帰]{かえ}り。」≂ お帰りなさい。 as a greeting
> 「お[休]{やす}み。」≂ お休みなさい。 as a greeting
> 「お[食]{た}べ。」"Eat it."
> 「お[上]{あ}がり。」"Please eat." / "Come in (家に)."
> 「お[入]{はい}り。」
> 「お[黙]{だま}り。」"Shut up."
> 「お[座]{すわ}り。」"Sit."
> 「おいで。」"Come here." (from お+[出]{い}で)